# Do different JVMS implement the same transformation differently?

Tags: encryption, java

I have encrypted a string - "EXAMPLE" on Oracle JDK 1.7 using the following code

```
//ENCRYPTION of "EXAMPLE"
byte[] clearText = {69, 88, 65, 77, 80, 76, 69};
KeyPair keyPair = EncodingTest.loadRSAKeyPair();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clearText); 
byte[] encoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedAES);
```

I then decode and decrypt the encoded string created above on an IBM JDK 1.7 platform using the following code

```
//DECRYPTION
byte[] encoded={83,74,97,99,110,79,84,97,76,85,106,79,120,88,83,70,110,104,86,55,48,70,57,121,57,72,102,116,54,70,49,68,71,112,97,97,110,72,87,107,119,86,72,47,122,47,114,100,84,79,115,88,101,117,109,122,83,50,99,115,114,76,54,102,118,100,116,82,79,68,80,83,70,107,119,90,101,89,106,88,122,117,69,109,49,77,113,51,120,104,116,68,99,120,114,82,118,82,99,50,120,78,74,43,121,55,53,88,67,75,50,85,88,118,88,78,74,43,49,121,55,76,87,116,110,51,105,79,77,119,107,88,68,53,78,51,54,111,110,50,69,49,99,102,57,57,55,48,119,52,107,81,116,116,111,77,74,69,112,48,111,82,112,100,99,113,104,101,47,89,79,98,69,78,49,49,57,77,77,79,109,52,106,66,54,113,86,82,53,121,119,43,101,65,77,104,107,104,75,82,85,87,80,121,97,111,84,66,112,104,83,103,51,114,110,98,115,120,67,109,48,105,69,77,100,106,72,118,118,102,103,103,75,105,79,109,76,50,86,77,116,106,82,52,43,122,108,69,48,120,52,89,75,118,109,115,116,78,54,53,100,85,51,100,83,102,53,57,113,43,103,53,106,121,50,97,78,72,115,68,67,69,105,71,82,80,80,103,69,72,113,47,97,109,50,111,108,88,119,78,116,52,114,99,110,48,90,79,108,55,49,67,74,88,89,107,79,102,110,102,51,103,78,65,108,81,73,56,105,120,97,66,65,99,109,80,76,77,54,72,81,103,61,61,};
byte[] encrypted  = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encoded);

Cipher decrCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding");
decrCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
byte[] decryptedAES = decrCipher.doFinal(encrypted);
```

This fails with a bad padding exception on the last line of code. However, the same decryption code works on the Oracle JDK.

I would have thought the transformations would be implemented the same across JVMS ? Am I missing something here - could someone please help ?

Thanks,
Ranjit

Comment: use search, this seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32166210/481815